# VHDL 3-8 decoder using if else syntax error near 'else' and 'process'

Tags: if-statement, syntax, vhdl, decoder

I've been trying to compile this program and tried to make edits according to my understanding of the error message that increased the amount of errors. This is the 2nd VHDL code I've ever written and I'm not sure what more I can do

this is the code:

```
    entity maashro3o is
port (Q: out bit_vector (0 to 7);
        A: in bit_vector(2 down to 0);
        en: in bit);
end maashro3o;

architecture maashro3o of maashro3o is
begin


process(A, en)
begin

if (en = "1") 
then 
    if (A = "000") 
    then
        Q <= "10000000";
    else if (A = "001") then
        Q <= "01000000";
    else if (A = "010") then
        Q <= "00100000";
    else if (A = "011") then
        Q <= "00010000";
    else if (A = "100") then
        Q <= "00001000";
    else if (A = "101") then
        Q <= "00000100";
    else if (A = "110") then
        Q <= "00000010";         
    else if (A = "111") then
        Q <= "00000001";    

END If;
    else
        Q <= "00000000";
End If;

end process;

end maashro3o
```

[image: this is the error message]

**Update**

I changed `else if` to `elsif` and `else` respectively.

[image: Now I'm getting all these errors]

I tried to remove `then` from `else` but I'm getting similar errors

```
    entity maashro3o is
port (Q: out bit_vector (0 to 7);
        A: in bit_vector(2 downto 0);
        en: in bit);
end maashro3o;

architecture maashro3o of maashro3o is
begin


process(A, en)
begin

if (en = '1') 
then 
    if (A = "000") 
    then
        Q <= "10000000";
    elsif (A = "001") then
        Q <= "01000000";
    else (A = "010") then
        Q <= "00100000";
    elsif (A = "011") then
        Q <= "00010000";
    else (A = "100") then
        Q <= "00001000";
    elsif (A = "101") then
        Q <= "00000100";
    else (A = "110") then
        Q <= "00000010";         
    elsif(A = "111") then
        Q <= "00000001";    

END If;
    else
        Q <= "00000000";
End If;

end process;

end maashro3o;
```

Comment: Syntax errors: 1) line 3, `downto` is a single reserved word 2) line 14, `en` is not a composite array type; use `'1'` not `"1"` 3) lines 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, `elsif` not `else if`4) line 41, missing final semicolon.

Comment: Note that simulators generally provide better error messages than synthesizers.

Comment: @user1155120 Thank you so much! I made the changes but now I'm getting more errors. I'm not sure if it's `then` or the brackets

Comment: There aren't any brackets in your code, only parentheses and [some of those aren't needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoQeV.jpg).

Comment: These `else`es:    `else (A = "010") then`, `else (A = "100") then`, `else (A = "110") then` should be an `elsif`s. You should be able to find all these syntax errors by proofreading.

Comment: @user1155120 at first I wrote them all as elsif but got similar errors and I wasn't sure which parenthesis I had to remove. I will try to use a simulator as per your suggestion it might improve things next time. thanks a bunch!

Comment: If you still get error after correcting the `else` es to `elsif`s please post the current code and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all the elses inside the block begins with

```
if (A="000") then
 .
 .
 .
end if;
```

There is no "else if" keyword in VHDL. Use "elsif". When coding an if-else statement with multiple conditions, you should not write else after elsif or vice versa. You can not use them both.

"else" keyword does not declare a specific statement. It is used for checking only one condition and doing something when condition is not satisfied.

Also when writing a VHDL code, don't forget to include the libraries you will need and may be need.

Corrected code is given below.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity maashro3o is
port (Q: out bit_vector (0 to 7);
        A: in bit_vector(2 downto 0);
        en: in bit);
end maashro3o;

architecture maashro3o of maashro3o is
begin


process(A, en)
begin

if (en = '1')  then 

    if (A = "000")  then
        Q <= "10000000";
    elsif (A = "001") then
        Q <= "01000000";
    elsif (A = "010") then
        Q <= "00100000";
    elsif (A = "011") then
        Q <= "00010000";
    elsif (A = "100") then
        Q <= "00001000";
    elsif (A = "101") then
        Q <= "00000100";
    elsif (A = "110") then
        Q <= "00000010";         
    elsif(A = "111") then
        Q <= "00000001";    
end if;

    else
        Q <= "00000000";
end if;

end process;

end maashro3o;
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to use if else statements only, since decoder is a combinational logic you can use case statement to design the logic, it will be more appropriate.